# Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]のエラー

Tags: php, mysql

### 前提

画像投稿掲示板を PHP, MySQL で作っています。
`posting.php` が投稿ページで、そのデータを `thanks.php` で受け取り、画像等一覧を
 `index.php` として表示したいです。
※ 今は仮として `thanks.php` に一覧を表示できるようしてます。

---

### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in /var/www/html/php_kadai/php_kadai09/thanks.php on line 16

データベースを見てもデータがinsertされていません・・・

```
<?php

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>画像投稿掲示板</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>画像投稿掲示板</h1>
<hr>
<p class="posting"><a href="posting.php">画像を投稿する</a></p>
<h2>投稿内容一覧</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>画像投稿ページ</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>画像投稿掲示板</h1>
<hr>
<form class="contents" action="thanks.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="table_basic">

<colgroup>
  <col width="33%" />
  <col width="67%" />
</colgroup>

  <tr>
    <th><span>投稿者</span><span class="must">必須</span></th>
    <td ><input type="text" name="name" value="" class="box">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th><span>画像タイトル</span><span class="must">必須</span></th>
    <td><input type="text" name="title" value="" class="box"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th><span>画像ファイル</span><span class="must">必須</span></th>
    <td><input type="file" name="uploadfile" value="選択してください"><br><span class="attension">（※png, jpgのみ対応）</span></td>
  </tr>

</table>
<p class="button"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="投稿する" width="50px"></p>
</form>
<p class="link"><a href="index.php">画像一覧ヘージはこちら>></a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<?php
require_once('functions.php');

$name = $_POST['name'];
$title = $_POST['title'];

$dbh = connectDb();

$sql = "insert into posts (create_at datetime, name, image_name, img_data) values
        (now(), :name, :title, :movetofile)";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":name", $name);
$stmt->bindParam(":title", $title);
$stmt->bindParam(":movetofile", $movetofile);

$stmt->execute();

//echo '成功しました';

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>投稿完了ページ</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

  <h1>画像投稿掲示板</h1>
  <hr>
<div id="wrapper">
  <p class="title">下記の内容で投稿致します</p>

  <p>投稿者：
    <?php if(empty($name)) :?>
      <?php echo "<p style='color:red;'>投稿者が入力されておりません。</p>"; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
      <?php echo h($name); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </p>

  <p class="imagestitle">画像タイトル：
    <?php if(empty($title)) :?>
      <?php echo "<p style='color:red;'>画像タイトルが入力されておりません。</p>"; ?>
     <?php else: ?>
      <?php echo h($title); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </p>
<p>画像ファイル：
<?php if(strlen($_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"]) > 0 ) :?>
  <?php $fileinfo = pathinfo($_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"]); ?>
  <?php $fileext = strtoupper($fileinfo["extension"]); ?>
  <?php $errmsg = ""; ?>
<?php if ($fileext != "PNG" and $fileext != "JPG") :?>
  <?php $errmsg .= "<p style='color:red;'>対象ファイルはPNGまたはJPGのみです！</p><br>"; ?>
<?php else: ?>
  <?php $movetofile = "images/upf_" . $_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"]; ?>
    <?php if (! move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadfile"]["tmp_name"], $movetofile)) :?>
      <?php $errmsg .= "<p style='color:red;'>ファイルのアップロードに失敗しました。</p><br>"; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($errmsg == "") :?>
  <?php echo $_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"] . "<br>"; ?>
  <?php echo "<img src='$movetofile'><br><br><br>"; ?>
<?php else: ?>
  <?php echo $errmsg . "<br><br><br>"; ?>
  <?php @unlink($_FILES["uploadfile"]["tmp_name"]); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php else: ?>
  <?php echo "<p style='color:red;'>アップロードするファイルが指定されていません！</p><br>"; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

</p>
  <p class="return"><a href="posting.php">画像投稿ページへ戻る>></a></p>
  <p class="link"><a href="index.php">画像一覧ヘージはこちら>></a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: ターミナルキャプチャー]

Comment: `$stmt->bindParam(":titile", $title);` となっていまして、正しくは `:title` ではないでしょうか…。それと、`:now()` となっている部分は `now()` の間違いでしょうか(コロンは不要？)。

Comment: @argus さん、ありがとうございます！エラーは解消されたのですが、データベースにデータがinsertされません。。。どんな原因があるのでしょうか？

Comment: Insert 文なのですけれども、`datetime` が余計な様な気がします。つまり、`insert into posts (create_at, name,  ...` となるのではないかと。

Comment: @argus さん、ありがとうございます！無事insertできました。ところが今度はimg_dataのフィールドがNULLになってしまい、うまくデータが保存できていないようです。画像データも（バイナリーデータ？として）データベースに保存したいのですが、記述しているコードが誤っているのでしょうか？

Comment: 確認ですが、MySQL 側のテーブルの img_data フィールドの型は何になっていますか？

Comment: @argus 型は「mediumblob」です！

Comment: 了解です。ただ、私には分かりかねますので、画像データの保存に関しての疑問点を質問欄に追加してはどうでしょうか。他の方から適切な回答が得られるかもしれませんので。

Comment: 少し調べてみましたが、`$fp = fopen($movetofile, 'rb'); $stmt->bindParam(":movetofile", $fp, PDO::PARAM_LOB);` という様にするらしいです。動作確認はしていないので、間違っていたらごめんなさい。